# intellij idea: не работает auto deploy с jetty

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

Привет, версия IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4, Build #IC-171.4694.23
настройки вроде по умолчанию, не чего толком не трогал.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
    <configuration>
        <reload>automatic</reload>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <httpConnector>
            <host>site.dev</host>
            <port>8080</port>
        </httpConnector>
        <stopKey/>
        <stopPort/>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Обновление срабатывает если к примеру изменить pom.xml, а на классах не хочет. Приходится нажимать на Rerun. В NetBeans работает все из коробки. Как включить в идее, не нашел.

Не работает и с этой галкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но с `Ctrl + F9` работает

Comment: а причем тут IDEA?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Может и не причем. В netBeans работало.

Comment: Что же, любимый нетбинс, возвращаюсь к тебе до решения вопроса) В netBeans все четко.

Comment: стоит удалить вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman почему. В идее как не работало, так и не работает.

Comment: вы же решили переключиться на другую IDE. поэтому вопрос потерял актуальность. если же нет, то добавьте в вопрос версию IDEA и информацию о настройках проекта.